# android set listview Item's height to Heighest of all children so looks like table with Border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, tableview, android-adapter

I am trying to show Dynamic TableView with the help of Listview and Adapter. I am setting Shape drawable for border.

Logically I m trying to get heighest Height among childs of the row and then setting that height to all child views.

For that I used  addOnGlobalLayoutListener , but Its called only once.
Let me know How can I achieve as Table.

I want to achieve Table , but as you can see Borders are not aPParing Proerly. Refer https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZyrc.png

Using Listview with Adapter

```
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final viewHoler holder;
                if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                    convertView =    inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflateordertakingproductview, null);
                    holder = new viewHoler();
                    holder.tvproductName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvitem);
                    holder.tvprice=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
                    holder.edqty=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edqty);
                    holder.edfree=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edfree);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder=(viewHoler)convertView.getTag();
                }
                ViewTreeObserver vto = holder.tvproductName.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        int height=0;

                        Log.v("Name Height",""+holder.tvproductName.getHeight());
                        Log.v("Price Height",""+holder.tvprice.getHeight());
                        Log.v("Edqty Height",""+holder.edqty.getHeight());
                        Log.v("Edfree Height",""+holder.edfree .getHeight());
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams  _lP=holder.tvproductName.getLayoutParams();
                        _lP.height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        holder.tvproductName.setLayoutParams(_lP);
                        holder.tvproductName.requestLayout();

                        _lP=holder.tvprice.getLayoutParams();
                        _lP.height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        holder.tvprice.setLayoutParams(_lP);
                        holder.tvprice.requestLayout();

                        _lP=holder.edqty.getLayoutParams();
                        _lP.height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        holder.edqty.setLayoutParams(_lP);
                        holder.edqty.requestLayout();

                        _lP=holder.edfree .getLayoutParams();
                        _lP.height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        holder.edfree.setLayoutParams(_lP);
                        holder.edfree.requestLayout();
                        if(holder.tvproductName.getHeight()>height){
                            height=holder.tvproductName.getHeight();
                        }
                        if(holder.tvprice.getHeight()>height){
                            height=holder.tvprice.getHeight();
                        }
                        if(holder.edqty.getHeight()>height){
                            height=holder.edqty.getHeight();
                        }
                        if(holder.edfree .getHeight()>height){
                            height=holder.edfree .getHeight();
                        }
                        Log.v("MAX Height",""+height);
                        _lP=holder.tvproductName.getLayoutParams();
                        _lP.height=height;
                        holder.tvproductName.setLayoutParams(_lP);
                        holder.tvproductName.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

                        _lP=holder.tvprice.getLayoutParams();
                        _lP.height=height;
                        holder.tvprice.setLayoutParams(_lP);
                        holder.tvprice.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        _lP=holder.edqty.getLayoutParams();
                        _lP.height=height;
                        holder.edqty.setLayoutParams(_lP);
                        holder.edqty.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        _lP=holder.edfree .getLayoutParams();
                        _lP.height=height;
                        holder.edfree .setLayoutParams(_lP);
                        holder.edfree .setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        holder.tvproductName.requestLayout();
                        holder.tvprice.requestLayout();
                        holder.edqty.requestLayout();
                        holder.edfree.requestLayout();

                        Log.v("Product Name",holder.tvproductName.getText().toString());
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            holder.tvproductName.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            holder.tvproductName.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                });
                hybridProductOffer _hp=_arrlist_product.get(position);
                String _price,_itemcode,_offerid;
                if(_hp.get_offerid()!=null ){
                    _price=_hp.get_offerprice();
                    _offerid=_hp.get_offerid();
                    holder.tvprice.setText( _hp.get_offermrp());
                }else{
                    _price=_hp.get_itemprice();
                    _offerid=null;
                    holder.tvprice.setText(_hp.get_itemprice());
                }
                _itemcode=_hp.get_itemcode();

                holder.tvproductName.setText(_hp.get_itemname());
                return convertView;
            }
```

Linear Layout XML :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="1" > 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvitem"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="@drawable/tableborderoffwhite"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp" /> 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvprice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/tableborderoffwhite"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp" /> 
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edqty"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/tableborderoffwhite"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp" /> 
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edfree"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/tableborderoffwhite"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance , Any helP aPPreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to have different height of listview rows (depends on the highest child's height in the layout) and implement the same height to all of the children.

Why don't you make the height of the children as "match_parent" ? Then you don't need to deal with the height of the children. And then you can set the parent layout's height as "wrap_content", so each layout will have the height of the highest child.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me going to Custom Views and all that.